# ldap query: need to do a query which retunrs all AD users who has either the attribute "mobilephone" or "Officephone" set to anything else but "NULL"

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

**ldap query:** need to do a query which retunrs all AD users who has either the attribute "mobilephone" or "Officephone" set to anything else but "NULL"

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? How about something like:

```
(&(objectclass=user)(|(!(mobilephone=null))(!(Officephone=null)))
```